# Getting ssl exception inspite of both certificates are issued by verified CA's?

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate

I have two webapplication at prrduction say app1 and app2. Both are on different webservers. app1 is verified secure trust corporation and 
app2 is verified by TrustWave Holdings,Inc . So both are verified CA's.App2 tries to make HttpsURLConnection to app1 and gets some SSLException. My question
is if both certificates  are verfied ones, still do we need to make any certificate entry in jre\lib\security folder? As per my understanding
we do not need this if certificates are verified one.  Any pointers will be great help.

**EDIT:-**

i am on jdk1.6. I am not sure whether these certificates i.e(secure trust corporation and TrustWave Holdings,Inc) are already there 
in cacerts file under jre\lib\security. i could find on the web that these are included in mozzila and other browser but not
sure about jdk 1.6?

Comment: Have you tried to list the cert providers using keytool -list -keystore ./security/cacerts

Comment: Is your webapp/webserver configured to require client authentication?

Comment: @tjg184 . Is there a way i can include trustwave and securetrust  in my cacert file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely need to add these to /security/cacerts.  By default Java does trust some certificate authorities.  I'm not sure TrustWave is one of them.

View the keystore using the following command and see if TrustWave is in there.

```
keytool -list -keystore /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_14/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Comment: my cacert file contains the 77 default entries .Most of them are by verisign, thawte but i do not see trustwave and securetrust anywhere there. How should i go to include them in my cacert file?

Comment: Try using the keytool -import command.  http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html

Answer (score 1):

It takes some effort from a provider to have its root CA cert included in all browsers and iphones and tablets and whatnots. More often than not they don't bother getting their cert shipped with oracle or openjdk. That's the exact reason why we moved away from Godaddy to Comodo... If the server cert isn't bundled you can create a keystore with the issuer certs and yours and tell java to use it via commandline:

> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=yourkeystorefile.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=yourkeystorefile.jks

*technically you would put the servers cert+key in the keystore and cert chain from the issuer to the truststore, but it's fine for java if the two are mixed in one keystore file*